# np.exp() is doubling the values

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm trying to plot a graph but I'm getting two times the number of y values that I'm supposed to get.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return np.exp(2*x)

x_plot=[0,1,2,3]
print(f(x_plot))
```

And i get the following:

```
[ 1.          2.71828183  7.3890561  20.08553692  1.          2.71828183
  7.3890561  20.08553692]
```

How can I plot a graph, since `x_plot` has 4 values and `f(x_plot)` has 8 values.

I've tried to change `numpy` to `math` but I still didn't get the values.

Comment: A debugging suggestion - don't assume that `np.exp` is doing the doubling.  Your function does a couple of things - you need to test both the `exp` and `2*x` parts.

Answer (score 3):

`x_plot` is a *list*, not an array. Multiplying a list is not the same as multiplying an array.

With a list, multiplication by `n` repeats the list `n` times.

```
>>> 2 * [0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

With an array, multiplication by `n` is done elementwise, so

```
>>> 2 * np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
array([0, 2, 4, 6])
```

You can see that it is not `np.exp` that is repeating your input values, it is the *multiplication of a list*.

To ensure your argument is an array before you multiply it, call [`np.asarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html):

```
def f(x):
    return np.exp(2*np.asarray(x))

x_plot=[0,1,2,3]
print(f(x_plot))
# [  1.           7.3890561   54.59815003 403.42879349]
```